# Fix first line on jupyter notebook output

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, html-table

I use this great code to show pyspark dataframes in jupyter in a nice format:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>pre { white-space: pre !important; }</style>"))
```

Thanks to user [eric-le-fort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857460/eric-le-fort)

**Question**:

How can I fix the first row to be able to see my column names with very long tables?
Thanks a lot

p.s. if you happen to know how to also set the horizontal scrollbar always to the bottom of the screen instead of the bottom of the output, that would be great.

Comment: have you tried this df.limit(max_rows + 1).show(max_rows, truncate=False)
and

Comment: and... ? Don't leave me hanging :-) 
The +1 did not fix the first line so far.

Comment: apologies "and" was a typo; if that does not work that means you have more than 20000-25000 rows  because truncate=False can show that much; another thing you can consider is using pagination